# Requiring a folder with same name as file in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I created a file named joke.js which exports a function. I also have a folder in the directory with the same name joke. In my node file, I want to use require to reference the folder and not the file. How do I tell Node to do that?

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YIKum.png)

So from the index.js in the root, I want to reference the joke directory and not the joke.js file.
I did:
`var joke=require('./joke');`

**P.S.-** This question is just out of curiosity of how NodeJS works.

Comment: `require('./joke/')` This will include .joke/index.js

Comment: This was really helpful, Thank you :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
require('./joke/')
```

A trailing slash is used to specify directory in any URI.